# sum function for update already data

Tags: codeigniter

i have 2 table, 1st tabel name `trans_tmbh_qty` for record history value inserted to tabel 2nd `frm_fancpu`
this my structure tabel 1st

[image]

and this tabel 2nd with name frm_monitor

[image]

this  now my full function on controller `trans_tmbh_qty`

```
public function create_action() 
{
    $this->_rules();

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->create();
    } else {
        $data = array(
    'merk' => $this->input->post('merk',TRUE),
    'av_mobo' => $this->input->post('av_mobo',TRUE),
    'av_prc' => $this->input->post('av_prc',TRUE),
    'av_ram' => $this->input->post('av_ram',TRUE),
    'av_hdd' => $this->input->post('av_hdd',TRUE),
    'av_psu' => $this->input->post('av_psu',TRUE),
    'av_fancpu' => $this->input->post('av_fancpu',TRUE),
    'user_modify_av' => $this->input->post('user_modify_av',TRUE),
    'date_modify_av' => $this->input->post('date_modify_av',TRUE),
    );

        $fancpu = $this->input->post('merk', TRUE);
         $av_fancpu = $this->input->post('av_fancpu', TRUE);
         $this->M_fancpu->av_fancpu($fancpu,$av_fancpu

    );
        $this->M_fancpu->av_fancpu($fancpu,$av_fancpu);
        $this->M_trans_tmbhqty->insert($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Create Record Success');
        redirect(site_url('trans_tmbhqty'));
    }
}
```

I want to update stock on `qty_available_fancpu`. if previously filled 10, and I inserted 5 on form. I need result 15. I have code now only replace number 10 with 5. and this my controller

```
 $fancpu = $this->input->post('merk', TRUE);
        $av_fancpu = array(
        'qty_available_fancpu' => $this->input->post('av_fancpu'),
    );
        $this->M_fancpu->av_fancpu($fancpu,$av_fancpu);
```

and it my model on M_fancpu

```
function av_fancpu($fancpu,$av_fancpu)
{ 
$this->db->where('tipe_fancpu', $fancpu);
$this->db->update('tbl_fancpu', $av_fancpu);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution for your problem :-

**Controller.php** file

```
class fancpu {
    $fancpu = $this->input->post('merk', TRUE);
    $av_fancpu = $this->input->post('av_fancpu', TRUE);
    $this->M_fancpu->av_fancpu($fancpu,$av_fancpu);
}
```

**Model.php** file

```
function av_fancpu($fancpu,$av_fancpu) { 
    $this->db->set('qty_available_fancpu', 'qty_available_fancpu + ' . (int) $av_fancpu, FALSE);
    $this->db->where('tipe_fancpu', $fancpu);
    $this->db->update('tbl_fancpu');
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: after I input "123" now I got these error, I dont understant with this error.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '123 = '' WHERE `tipe_fancpu` = 'LGA'' at line 1

UPDATE `tbl_fancpu` SET qty_available_fancpu = qty_available_fancpu + 0, 123 = '' WHERE `tipe_fancpu` = 'LGA

Comment: Wow,, Its work. but if I insert 5 in database reading I insert 10. ex: already value on table 5, I insert on form 5. result in database is 15, not 10.
sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please explain more with setup of Input value before and after execute update query and also post table structure with data.

Comment: Please check your controller inside two times call function `av_fancpu` correct and check now.